# How to write a wordpress query when there are multiple values in custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a wordpress custom post type with custom fields. Initially the requirement was every post has only one pin "Say example" 1001 and all posts with custom fields has 1001 needs to be retrieved. I used query args as

```
<?php
 $args = array(
 'post_type'=> array('sales'),
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'meta_key'=> 'pin',
 'meta_value'=> $pin
 );
 query_posts( $args );                      
?>
```

Now I can have multiple zips in single custom field.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pk53z23jbfj8p2t/zipcode.png?dl=0

How the query needs to be altered so if the entered zip matched any one of the item on the filed, post is displayed.

So for example the custom field has values 63001,63002,63003 and so on. So if user enters 63002 all the posts with 63002 in the custom field needs to be displayed.

Comment: If you have code then please share for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'=> array('sales'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array( array(
       'key'=> 'pin',
       'value'=> ','.$pin.',',
       'compare'=> 'LIKE'
    ) )
 );
 query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: hi @jayadip its working but returning only 1 result even there are multiple posts. I am debugging it. Do you have any idea of what the issue is. Thanks buddy for your help.

Comment: It seems to me like this wouldn't work if `$pin` were the first or last value in the list of `pin`s.

Answer (score 0):

try update your post meta value in json type by json_encode and get that by json_decode